# Sharing mutual data between few same python scripts

Tags: python, docker, threadpool, sharing

I wonder if there is any kind of technics to share data between same-same python scripts or with multiple docker containers where those scripts to be run.

Here is the config file we need to get data from. And we take data and use it. And we need to track which data is taken by a Process/Thread from this file or whatever and put it as a reference to some place. Should it be a file where we store all taken fields from the config file so we could know which data is already taken not to take it again by different Threads/Processes.

```
appname: PutinGoAway

locations:
  - 13640165
  - 359545221
  - 274885506
  - 216416212
  - 2223530227690686

vars:
  download_boundary : 10
  extension  : .jpg

redis:
    host: 'localhost'
    port:  6379


aws:
  endpoint:
    play.min.io
  access_key:
    Q3AM3UQ867SPQQA43P2F
  secret_key:
    zuf+tfteSlswRu7BJ86wekitnifILbZam1KYY3TG
  region:
    eu-west-1
    eu-central-1
  bucket:
    pictures
```

Comment: Can you clarify your use-case? In "share data between same-same python scripts or with multiple docker containers" the first is doable, the second can be difficult to impossible depending on your setup. Also, be aware that just because you know which data was taken does not mean you know which data was processed - you likely need to worry about tracking and re-running failed tasks.

Comment: Well, it's necessary to switch between locations in our script in some cases. E.g. when we send a request to some API in a given location and a request gets rejected and we caught an error as we exceeded limit of request to location itself. So I need to handle the error and rerun script with different location id, as previous one is in blacklist already.